# Express routes never execute while running Mocha tests with Supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Here's a route that works when running the app and hitting it directly with Postman:

```
router.get("/profile", function(req, res) {
  var schema = schemas.filter(function(e) { return e.route === "profile"; }).pop();

  if (schema !== undefined) {
    var schemaJson = require(schema.schemaFile);
    return res.status(200).send(schemaJson);
  }
});
```

And here's a test:

```
var schemas = require("../../conf/schemas"),
  api_key = require("../../conf/api-keys").pop().key,
  app = require("../../app"),
  request = require("supertest");

    describe("CDM API Get Schema Operations", function() {
      it("Returns 404 for schema that do not exist", function (done) {
        request(app)
          .get("/schemas/profile")
          .end(function(err, res) {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(500);
            //expect(res.body.thing).to.not.equal(null);
            done()
          });
      });
    });
```

Running in debug mode, the expect statement is reached, always with an error. The code in the route is never reached.

My app.js file does export the app object (which is an Express object).

```
var express = require('express'),
  logger = require('morgan'),
  body_parser = require('body-parser');

var cdm_gateway = require('./middleware/cdm-gateway'),
  v1_gateway = require('./middleware/v1-gateway'),
  schema_routes = require('./routes/schema'),
  member_routes = require('./routes/member');

var app = express();

app.use(cdm_gateway);
app.use("/v1", v1_gateway);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(body_parser.json());
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/v1/schemas', schema_routes);
app.use('/v1/member', member_routes);

// Error handling
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500)
      .send('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500)
    .send('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

app.server = app.listen(3030);

module.exports = app;
```

The error usually contains an unsupported status code method.

Comment: Can we see the `module.exports` of `../../app`?

Comment: Thanks. Your question seems to state that your routes are a) never being hit but also b) the expect is being hit in your supertest. If the expect is being hit then your routes are also being hit. Are you sure the expect is being hit in supertest? If there is an error, what does that error say?

Comment: Positive it's being hit - I'm using Webstorm and it's hitting that line's breakpoint. It does not, however, hit a breakpoint at any time in that route file.

Error is: HPE_INVALID_STATUS / invalid status

Comment: Hi, that error seems to be [pretty bad news indeed](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8760). I'm not sure what could cause it, but there's definitely something bad going on there that's unrelated to supertest/express/node.

Comment: So the thing is, if I just run the app and make a request to postman, it works fine. I get the expected response from that endpoint, no issues. There are no other moving parts to interfere.

Comment: I have to head off, but in case other people can answer your question, what versions of supertest, express and node are you using?

Comment: Does the test pass if you run the express server independently (instead of requiring app) and issue requests to localhost:3030/schemas/profile?

Comment: Yes, they do @veggiesaurus

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be an issue with WebStorm. After a re-install and fresh configuration, it worked fine. I don't really have an explanation beyond that.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer now that the 2 day period has passed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, changing your route and middleware:

```
    router.get("/profile", function(req, res, next) {
      var schema = schemas.filter(function(e) { return e.route === "profile"; }).pop();

      if (schema !== undefined) {
        var schemaJson = require(schema.schemaFile);
        return res.status(200).send(schemaJson);
      } else {
        var error = new Error('Not Found');
        error.status = 404;
        next(error);
      }
    });
```

```
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res
        .status(err.status || 500)
        .send({
          message: err.message,
          error: {}
        });
    });
```